# How can i use splitter ^ in java

Tags: java, split, caret

I have a problem with my java program. I have to read lines from a file, the form of these lines is:

- 1#the^cat#the^dog#the^bird#^fish#bear
- 2#the^cat#the^dog#the^bird#^fish#bear

and print all, accept the "#" and "^" at textfields in my GUI. The "^" must appear in case there in not article. For exaple ^fish, i have to print it as ^fish but the^dog i have to print the dog.
As far i can read and print the lines in the textfields but i can't find a way to skip the "^" between the words.

**Here is my code:**

```
try {
        FileReader file = new FileReader("C:\\Guide.txt");
        BufferedReader BR = new BufferedReader(file);
        boolean eof = false;
        int i=0;
        while (!eof) {
            String line = BR.readLine();
            if (line == null) 
                eof = true;
            else {
                i++;
                System.out.println("Parsing line "+i+" <"+line+">");
                String[] words = line.split("#"); 
                if (words.length != 7) continue;
                number=words[0]; 
                onomastiki=words[1]; 
                geniki=words[2]; 
                aitiatiki=words[3]; 
                klitiki=words[4]; 
                genos=words[5];
                Region=words[6];

                E = new CityEntry(number,onomastiki,geniki,
                    aitiatiki,klitiki,
                    genos,Region);
                Cities.add(E);
            }
```

Comment: After splitting with #, next you have to iterate an array and check if array element contains ^, then split with ^ and store in variable for further operation.

Comment: Thank you, i 'll try it !!!!

Comment: According to the sample lines you posted, if you split the line by `#` character, I only see 6 words and not 7, e.g. `1#the^cat#the^dog#the^bird#^fish#bear` after split gives `1`, `the^cat`, `the^dog`, `the^bird`, `^fish` and `bear`, so I don't understand this line of the code you posted: `if (words.length != 7) continue;` What am I missing?

Comment: You right about number 7. It is 6. My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

```
    FileReader file = new FileReader("C:\\\\Users\\\\aq104e\\\\Desktop\\\\text");

    BufferedReader BR = new BufferedReader(file);
    boolean eof = false;
    int i = 0;
    while (!eof) {
        String line = BR.readLine();
        if (line == null)
            eof = true;
        else {
            i++;
            System.out.println("Parsing line " + i + " <" + line + ">");
            String[] words = line.split("#");               

            for (int j = 0; j < words.length; j++) {
                if(words[j].contains("^")) {
                    if(words[j].indexOf("^") == 0) {
                        // write your code here
                        //This is case for ^fish
                    }else {

                        // split using ^ and do further manipulations
                    }
                }

            }

        }
    }
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: I will try it and i 'll inform you.

Answer (score 0):

That is gonna work, but it is not best way)

```
foreach(String word : words){
   if(word.contains"the"){
      word.replace("^"," ");
   }
}
```